# Calculate lift for context-state relationship in a probabilistic suffix tree?

Tags: r, markov-chains, pst, traminer, sequence-analysis

`PST` gives me probabilities and conditional probabilities for various contexts and following states. However, it would be very helpful to be able to calculate the lift (and its significance) of the relationship between a context and a following state. How can I do this?

```
# Load libraries
library(RCurl)
library(TraMineR)
library(PST)

# Get data
x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/08228977353bf6dc2edb3ec121f54a29/raw/c2539d06771317c5f4c8d3a2052a73fc485a09c6/challenge_level.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)

# Load and transform data
data <- read.table("thread_level.csv", sep = ",", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Create sequence object
data.seq <- seqdef(data[2:nrow(data),2:ncol(data)], missing = NA, right= NA, nr = "*")

# Make a tree
S1 <- pstree(data.seq, ymin = 0.05, L = 6, lik = TRUE, with.missing = TRUE)

# Look at first state
cmine(S1, pmin = 0, state = "N3", l = 2)
```

This gives several contexts, one of them being:

```
[>] context: N2 
       EX         FA         I1         I2   I3         N1        N2         N3        NR         QU
S1 0.07692308 0.08076923 0.05769231 0.07692308 0.05 0.06923077 0.1038462 0.06153846 0.1269231 0.07307692
       TR         *
S1 0.08076923 0.1423077
```

Let's say I wanted to calculate the lift of the relationship between `QU` and `N3`. We know that the conditional probability of `N3` given `N2` is `0.05`. To calculate the lift, would I then just [divide the conditional probability by the unconditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(data_mining)) of the resultant state, like so:

```
0.05/unconditional probability of N3
```

If we do `seqstatf(data.seq)` we can see that the fraction of `N3` markers is `0.01721715`. Would that then mean that the lift is:

```
0.05/0.01721715=2.90408110518
```

or would it be more appropriate to take the probability of `N3` given `e` as stated by `cmine(S1, pmin = 0, state = "N3", l = 1)`, i.e. `0.001554569`? This would yield a lift of:

```
0.05/0.001554569=32.163255539
```

which is substantially higher...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is correct. However, the problem with `seqstatf` is that it does not take the missing state (`*`) into account. Here is how you can get the overall probability of `N3`

```
nN3 <- sum(data.seq == 'N3')
nn <- nrow(data.seq)*ncol(data.seq)
(pN3 <- nN3/nn)
```

which gives `0.001556148`.

So the lift would be here

```
ctx <- cmine(S1, pmin = 0, state = "N3", l = 2)
(liftN3 <- ctx$N2[,"N3"]/pN3)
```

i.e., `39.5`.

An alternative that could make more sense would be to consider the conditional probabilities when we exclude the missing state, i.e., those obtained with a tree without the missing state.